# Display of class instances?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, pointers

The code below is for constructing a linked list.

I created an instance of Node named a, and gave it an item 'hello', and created an instance of a Node named b, and then gave it a value `'world'`, and then did `a.setOther(b)`;

When I then type `a.getOther()` I don't get 'world', but I get `<__main__.Node at 0x140ae7fafd0>`.

Is this like a pointer, giving the location of the data on my disk? If so, how do I then display the data from this location?

```
 class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, item, other = None):
        self.item = item
        self.other = other

    def getItem(self):
        return self.item

    def getOther(self):
        return self.other

    def setItem(self, item):
        self.item = item

    def setOther(self, other):
        self.other = other
```

Comment: The first part of the question is a duplicate. The second part might be as well, though not as obviously. You need to use `a.getOther()` rather than `a.getOther` if you want to invoke the method -- but why bother with getters and setters? It is dated, but the following is worth a read: http://dirtsimple.org/2004/12/python-is-not-java.html Or this: http://www.python-course.eu/python3_properties.php

Comment: Ok, thanks. I'm going to edit the post to only the second half of the question. I also noticed I made an error - I meant to say `a.getOther()` not `a.getOther`

Comment: You're getting `<__main__.Node at 0x140ae7fafd0>` because the `Node` class doesn't define a `__str__` or `__repr__` method, so something generic is used.

Comment: @teddyv hope this solves your problem! http://stackoverflow.com/a/42191677/6840615

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an issue, really, the code works okay and you can verify that `getOther` does the right thing by a simple equality:

```
a.getOther() == b
True
```

the issue is that when you execute `a.getOther()` the interpreter will call the `__repr__` of the object returned to print it out. If you need a custom representation, you'll need to specify it by adding a `__repr__`:

```
def __repr__(self):
   return "Node({0}, {1})".format(self.item, self.other)
```

the output of `__repr__` should ideally be similar to the statement you'd use to construct the `Node` object.

Similarly, you'll need to define a `__str__` if you print an object using `print` and wanted a more user friendly representation for the user.

Answer (score 0):

> I created an instance of Node named a, and gave it an item 'hello',and created an instance of a Node named b, and then gave it a value 'world',

```
a = Node('hello')
b = Node('world')
```

> and then did `a.setOther(b);`

```
a.setOther(b)
```

> When I then type `a.getOther()` I don't get `'world'`

`setOther(b)` is storing a reference of `Node b`; when `a.getOther()` is called  (in your code)you simply returned `return self.other` which is the address of the reference; whereas you needed the `item` inside the `Node b`.
so you should have instead returned `return self.other.item`

**Try this:**

```
def getOther(self):
   return self.other.item
```